# How to calculate temperature and entropy on Schwarzschild-de Sitter space

Tags: general-relativity, greens-functions, de-sitter-spacetime, black-hole-thermodynamics

The cosmological event horizon found in a de Sitter universe has some interesting similarities to that of a black hole. For example, since we can find a temperature at the horizon, we are able to use the relation $S = A/4G$ to calculate the entropy of the horizon related to it's surface.

I am looking for a method of directly calculating the entropy, instead of using the famous relation given above. One example I found was mentioned in [Les Houches Lectures on De Sitter Space](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0110007) (pages 17,18). Unfortunately, the method is given as an exercise, and the conclusion given is far from obvious (to me).

They start by looking at the static Schwarzschild-de Sitter metric in three dimensions given by $$ds^2 = -\left(1 - 8GE - r^2\right)\,dt^2 + \dfrac{dr^2}{1-8GE-r^2} + r^2 d\theta^2 $$

The paper states that finding a Green's function for $SdS_3$ by analytic continuation from the smooth Euclidian solution periodic in $\tau \rightarrow \tau + \dfrac{2 \pi i}{\sqrt{1 - 8GE}}$ will give all required answers to find the entropy (the authors calculate temperature invoking a thermodynamic identity and they finish off with $S$).

I have yet to find another paper that uses this derivation, but I am quite interested in the part missing. Is there someone who can shed a light on how finding such a Green's function leads to temperature and entropy?

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking for a method of directly calculating the entropy, instead of using the famous relation (...) how finding such a Green function leads to temperature/entropy?

What you need is Green's functions' period, i.e. period $\beta$ on imaginary time. You can calculate this merely by removing the '*singularity*' at the horizon. (At least) for any metric of the type
$$ds^2=-f(r)\,dt^2+f^{-1}(r)\,dr^2+r^2\,d\Omega^2\tag{1}$$
let
$$f(r_+)=0\tag{2}$$
then if you look near $r_+$, say for $r=r_++\epsilon^2$, at the lowest order,
$$f(r_++\epsilon^2)\simeq\epsilon^2f^\prime(r_+)\tag{3}$$
and thus the metric here looks like
$$ds^2=-\epsilon^2f^\prime(r_+)\,dt^2+4\epsilon^2\left[\epsilon^2f^\prime(r_+)\right]^{-1}\,d\epsilon^2+(r_++\epsilon^2)^2\,d\Omega^2\tag{4}$$
Now, letting $t=i\tau$,
\begin{align}ds^2&=\epsilon^2f^\prime(r_+)\,d\tau^2+4\epsilon^2\left[\epsilon^2f^\prime(r_+)\right]^{-1}\,dr^2+(r_++\epsilon^2)^2\,d\Omega^2\\&=\frac{4}{f^\prime(r_+)}\left[d\epsilon^2+\left(\frac{f^\prime(r_+)}{2}\right)^2\epsilon^2d\tau^2\right]+(r_++\epsilon^2)^2\,d\Omega^2\tag{5}\end{align}
and so, in order to avoid a conical singularity, you should have
$$\frac{\left|f^\prime(r_+)\right|}{2}\int_0^\beta\int_0^{r_+}\epsilon\,d\epsilon\,d\tau=\pi{r}_+^2\,\Longrightarrow\,\beta=\frac{4\pi}{\left|f^\prime(r_+)\right|}\tag{6}$$
In this case $f(r)=1-8GE-r^2$, and so $\left|f^\prime(r_+)\right|=2r_+$ where $r_+=\sqrt{1-8GE}$. Then you just use $T=\beta^{-1}$ and (71) on "Les Houches Lectures" to get temperature and entropy.

This is the easiest way I know; I openly avoided Green's functions as that seem to be another question, and one that someone else can answer better than me.